# Position of Points (blender 3.0 beta)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a curve in Geo nodes and i want to get the position of Points on the curve
I've tried to convert curve to points but there is no way to get the position of curve points as List (Fields)

Comment: Dou you want to use the 'List' of positions inside the node-tree, or export them for use outside the modifier?

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I need it inside of node tree

Comment: maybe you should tell us what your "end goal" is...what kind of effect to you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you Chris
I wanna make a set of line between two curves that I made them earlier in geo nodes 
In fact i have two spirals and i want to make bridges between them (Like DNA shape)

Comment: So the answers to this question all give the specifics of how to make DNA, but what about the original question? Is it possible to access the position of a point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For DNA like structure you can do like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice!!! Geometry nodes is getting more and more amazing!

Comment: Yes it is already very powerful

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyyyyyy much

Comment: Ignoring that the question asked about making 
DNA, is there a way to get the position of a point?

Answer (score 1):

Another easy and accurate solution:

Connect lines from start and end points
[image]

DNA like structure created using `Connect Lines` group node
[image]